# mailboxer gem & db setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql, mailboxer

I'm trying to deploy my rails 4 app with mailboxer gem.

I am getting a PG error that says:

```
PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table conversations because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint notifications_on_conversation_id on table notifications depends on table conversations
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
: DROP TABLE "conversations"
```

I don't want to drop the table. Any advice for how to resolve this issue would be very much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, you have a Rails migration that does want to drop it. I suggest looking at your Rails migration files. (Also, make sure you have good backups).

Comment: Hi Craig, what should I be looking for in my migration files?